# Change font size of boxplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of three boxplots in the same plot, using `ggplot2`. Let's assume that the y axis measures time and it's labeled as "Time." The x axis indicates the groups and is labeled as "Groups." However, the name of each individual group is "Group 1", "Group 2", and "Group 3". I know how to change the size for  the x axis and y axis, but I don't know how to change the font size for the labels for each boxplot. The default font size is too small, and I'd like to increase it. How can I make the font for "Group 1/2/3" bigger ? I have looked all over, but I have not been unsuccessful. Can someone provide code for a `ggplot2` plot so that I can see how to do that? Or is it not possible to do?

Below is some basic code of what I have so far:

```
ggplot(data=myfile, aes(x=group, y=time) +

  geom_boxplot() +

  labs(title = "My graph", x = "Groups", y = "Time") +

  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(size = 14, hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 14),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 14)
  )
```

**Update:** I have added an image to exemplify exactly what I want.

[Plot with three boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6tgB.png)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but perhaps `axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14)`?

Comment: I have updated my question to include an image. I want to change the font size for the words "initial" "medial" and "final". The code `axis.text.x =element_text(size=14)` only changes the word "Position."

Comment: @Ernesto I think you mis-copied. `axis.title.x` will only change the the word "Position". Axeman suggests `axis.text.x`, which will change the tick labels, "initial", "medial", and "final".

Comment: And, FYI, theme settings will be inherited. So instead of specifying both `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y`, if you want them the same you can use a single `axis.title`.

Comment: Ohhh! I see. It worked. Thank you @Gregor. Also, thank you for letting me know that these labels are called "ticks." It might help in the future.

Comment: @Axeman, also thank you for your help, and sorry for misunderstanding your response.

Comment: The little marks on the axis are the ticks. These are the labels of the ticks.